# How to code CSS changes locally for a hosted domain?

Tags: css

What tool/editor do you recommend to (live) test your local CSS changes against an externally hosted site?

*A site lives on a domain.test (no server access), and I need to write extensive CSS overrides to reskin the entire site. All changes will be in a single CSS file with no preprocessor.*

The ideal setup is using the comfort of my regular code editor (Visual Studio Code) and having the site open in a browser and have the CSS auto-refresh as I save my CSS changes in a local directory.

It's a big site, so I'm open to setting up a complex setup rather than relying on testing edits using browser inspect mode or mounting CSS files using Firefox.

:: *I can inject JS script/library to the site if it helps with my setup.*

***Bonus: If I can do that for Vanilla JS too.***

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows with ModHeader and ScriptAutoRunner (chrome extensions).

1. With ModHeader replace the site's CSS and JS to local files using the "Redirect URL" function. (If necessary use ScriptAutoRunner to inject JS).
2. In one of these JS files create a rule to download every 2 seconds via ajax (any other way) your local files and check if there is equality with the last request or not. If the file has changed then reload the page (to update).

I know there are some tools that show CSS changes in real time without you having to reload, but I don't use them and the way I mentioned you can also make them run when the JS is updated.